# How can Bioshock Infinite saves on the PC be backed up and restored?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

Because the game doesn't support multiple save points, I need to make a backup of my progress so my partner can play too.

I've found the save data in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\XXXX\8870\remote\savedata but making a copy, and later restoring it, doesn't work. I've lost all my progress! I have disabled Steam cloud support in the in-game options, but my original save game is never recognized and I can only start a new game.

Comment: Please do not put the answer in the question. In 24 hours, you can self answer if no one already has.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot, Perhaps that rule needs a review. The 2k+ users who viewed this question in the last 10 hours might be wanting to know too.

Answer (score 5):

You have to disable Steam Cloud support in the game, and also in Steam.

- In the game, go to the options screen->gameplay and set Steam cloud
  to off.
- In Steam, right-click Bioshock Infinite in your games list
  and select Properties. Choose the Updates tab and uncheck 'Enable
  Steam Cloud synchronization for Bioishock Infinite'.

After you have finished playing, **exit from Steam** and cut/paste the C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\XXXX\8870\ folder somewhere safe. Copy/paste it back when you want to restore that particular save.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that fully exiting from Steam is necessary, as this answer mentions.  I spent hours trying to get saves I had backed up both via Gamesave Manager and manually to show up in the game before I tried performing the restore with Steam closed thanks to this answer.  I had disabled steam cloud from both Steam and in-game already, but that had been insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the auto-save, or replay chapters after you've finished them, but that's it. No manual saves here.